# Add a line prior to quoted message in Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

When replying to an email in Outlook, it quotes the message of the sender.

I would like Outlook to automatically add a line prior to the message of the sender containing information about the message, e.g.:

```
On Sep 17, 2014, at 1:29 PM, John Smith <jsmith@jsmith.com> wrote:

> Sender's original message goes here.
```

A lot of mail clients can do this. They even allow you to customize the look of the line to your liking.

Is there any way to do this in Outlook 2013?

Answer (score 1):

You can customize to *some degree* the quotation formatting, but the reply header is not. You have to use a third party software. One that reportedly works (have not personally tested yet) is [Outlook quote fix](http://home.in.tum.de/~jain/software/outlook-quotefix/). The default reply header is not what you described, but you can customize the default to build a typical internet header. Groupwise 2012 has this feature already out of the box, but in typical Microsoft fashion they would declare the new standard darkness if a lightbulb needed to be replaced.

The relevant passage in the above link is:

> **Quote Header Styles**
>   Brings up a dialog that allows you to select your favourite attribution line(s). You can choose between the normal quote header (Outlook), a short header, a short header with email address, no header at all and a *custom* header which you can define according to your needs.

You can also try this site since outlook quote fix seems to be abandoned: http://sourceforge.net/projects/macros4outlook/